# Making WIFI application in Java, and Making network application in java which uses WIFI as source of Internet is same thing?

Tags: java

Some where searching on stackoverflow, it came to my knowledge that Java does not support making wifi application (for example an application that can share file using WiFI) but Java support network application based on TCP using socket or serversocket class. So Can I make a java application that can communicate through WIFI internet?

Comment: "Some where searching on stackoverflow" could you please cite this claim.

Comment: A question like this, requesting the community to give an YES/NO answer is not very helpful. You should first do your basic research - find some examples, try them out and if you encounter problems, you can post a more direct question.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your concern is about how to transfer information over a network. The transfer of data doesn't depend on the type of technology you use, whether it is cabled or wireless. You can communicate over a network if the ip address, port number and authentication of the sending and receiving ends are correctly configured. I guess it is better if you have a little bit of knowledge about Data Communication and Computer Networking to understand that.